# The Drude model and Casimir force

Tags: condensed-matter, electrical-resistance, casimir-effect

Some years ago I have read a paper (which I could not find now) where it was argued that using the Drude model to calculate the Casimir force between real metals does not make  any sense because the very purpose of this model is to describe dissipative effects (such as resistance and Ohmic heating)  while in the context of a  Casimir force experiment there are  no such things.  I tend to agree with this, but what  are the current opinions on the  matter?

Answer (score 0):

The Drude model is a purely classical model of electrons considered to be a gas of free particles (little billiard balls) in the metal interacting by collisions with the ions of the metal and thus exchanging energy with the crystal. In its simplest derivation assuming classical boundary conditions for the electromagnetic field, the  Casimir force arises from consideration of the dependence of the zero point energy of the quantized electromagnetic field between metal plates on distance.

Comment: The question was if the use of the Drude more here is appropriate, and somehow you avoided it.

Comment: By the way, I  know well enough where Casimir force comes from, do not look at my reputation score.

Comment: @AlexGavrilov - Sorry, I am not an expert in the Casimir force or quantum electrodynamics. I only stated, that in its simplest derivation, only the electromagnetic boundary  conditions of electrical and magnetic fields at a perfect metal surface are used. Thus no explicit reference to any  model for the electrons in the metal is invoked. Maybe you can find a model based on a detailed description of the electrons in the metal in one of the papers of the group of Evgeny Lifshitz (co-author of Lev Landau of the famous "Course of Theoretical Physics") who has also  worked on this topic.

Comment: The point is, the Drude model and the  standard  derivation of the Casimir force (following Lifshitz) are probably based on mutually contradictory assumptions. I want to clarify this.